# Laggy string search, how can it be improved?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that i use to search for a spesific string in the innerText of elements with a certain class name. When it finds a match it gives that element a display of block to show and if not display none to hide. When i use this to search (i have about 3 thousand elements with same class) it takes a few seconds (about 5s) before it completes. Is there a more performance based way to write this code and maybe cut a second or two?

```
function searchClass(ClassName, Value){
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName(ClassName);
    var val = Value.toLowerCase().trim();
    for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){
        if(c[i].innerText.toLowerCase().trim().indexOf(val) > -1){
            c[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            c[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

PS. there is a keyup event that triggers the function.

**EDIT: (solution)** My search is instantly alot faster just by changing innerText to textContent and some small changes thanks to comments!

Comment: You could just set all of them to display none in css and then show what needs to be shown(no need to set display none in js), Also cache `c[i]`. If you can trigger this on type complete instead of keyup, it would probably help a lot. Use a loading spinner if you have to so the user doesn't think nothing is happening when loading

Comment: How often is the function triggered?

Comment: Using vanilla JS is already a great step for optimized performance. The only other thing I see is that you could save `c[i]` to a local variable, but that will probably not increase performance too much.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean to do? In this way we can avoid answers that don't fit your problem

Comment: It might be faster to keep the strings in memory as an array, already preprocessed to be lower-case and trimmed, search that instead and *then* use the results to update the DOM. I'd need to see more code (ideally a full site that demonstrates the issue) and run tests to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pre-increment is faster than post-increment when you don't need the previous value, and you don't, so switch to pre-increment in the for loop (although id expect today's competitve js engines to auto-optimize this, gcc has done this for ages on -O1 and higher)

also, unless you have a lot of script elements, textContent should be a lot faster than innerText, so switch to textContent... other than that, i don't see much room for improvement